# Jersey REST web service get web project URL

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a simple REST web service with Jersey, and I have only one resource class, named **categorizer**.

This resource will return a HTML form for a **GET** request. When the user fills this HTML form, it will send a **POST** request to the same resource class, i.e. **categorizer**. So my question turns to be how can I get the correct URL for **action** field in the HTML form, which is returned for the **GET** request. I wish this URL could be dynamic. In other words, it will work when it is deployed on different servers with different domain name (IP address).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: See the answers for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892622/how-do-i-find-the-url-of-my-web-service

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use JSP in conjunction with Jersey and dynamically create the HTML page you need. An example for this can be found [on this page](http://blog.usul.org/using-jsp-in-a-jersey-jax-rs-restful-application/).

Hope this helps.