# Injection error while trying to get WebServiceContext in RESTful WS with Java Jersey

Tags: java, rest, maven, dependency-injection

I'm using Jersey for RESTFul Web Services in Java and I'm trying to get the caller IP address within the Java Method, without passing as a parameter.

I tried several other posts with similar questions in StackOverflow but none of them worked. So far I got an error of injection, and I don't know how to solve it.

This piece of code needs to run inside a Tomcat 8 container in one server and JBoss in another server. But when I deploy the project to any of them, the same error is thrown while starting container:

***SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext com.adamiworks.restfultutorial.JsonService.webServiceContex*t**

This error also occurs when running from eclipse to Tomcat 8.

Can anyone point me out where I'm wrong?

I have this class:

```
package com.adamiworks.restfultutorial;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

@Path("/json")
public class JsonService {

    @Context
    WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonObject getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        HttpServletRequest request = this.getHttpContext();

        String clientIpAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = sdf.parse("1984-01-08");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        c.setNome("Anyone");
        c.setDataNascimento(d);

        JsonObject o = new JsonObject(msg, c);
        o.setText("IP=" + clientIpAddress);

        return o;
    }

    private HttpServletRequest getHttpContext() {

        MessageContext mc = webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
        return request;
    }

}
```

With this pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.adamiworks</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>adamiworks restful-tutorial</name>
    <description>restful-tutorial ftw</description>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <jersey.version>1.19.3</jersey.version>
        <javax.ws.rs.version>1.1.1</javax.ws.rs.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.ws.rs.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a lot of people, including

[HRITUPON](http://designdeft.blogspot.com.br/2015/06/solution-jersey-severe-missing.html)

[Everyone Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346630/jax-ws-webservicecontext-remains-null-annotation-injection-fails)

[And everyone here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163874/get-real-client-ip-in-a-servlet)

I finally made it!

Turns out that:

1. Context Injection are not available in Jersey 1.x.x - need to upgrade to version 2+.
2. Jersey versions starting from 2.x.x are now maintained by Glassfish, so there is a lot of differentes in pom.xml and web.xml;
3. WebServiceContext and MessageContext are SOAP based does not have meaning in a Java RESTFul Web Service, since does not receive the specific SOAP headers.

For thos who are struggling with the same errors, please take note of my changes below:

**pom.xml**: Changed to Jersey 2.24.1

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.adamiworks</groupId>
<artifactId>restful-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>adamiworks restful-tutorial</name>
<description>restful-tutorial ftw</description>
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <jersey.version>2.24.1</jersey.version>
    <javax.ws.rs.version>1.1.1</javax.ws.rs.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**web.xml** Changed Servlet classes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>restful-tutorial</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.adamiworks.restfultutorial</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**The Java Class with the service**: Please ignore other classes that are out of context.

```
package com.adamiworks.restfultutorial;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/json")
public class JsonService {

    @Context
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonObject getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        // This is the method that get the correct IP address
        String clientIpAddress = getClientIpAddr();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = sdf.parse("1984-01-08");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        c.setNome("Anyone");
        c.setDataNascimento(d);

        JsonObject o = new JsonObject(msg, c);
        o.setText("IP=" + clientIpAddress);

        return o;
    }

    public String getClientIpAddr() {
        String ip = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");

        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
        }
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
        }
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
        }
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
        }
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        }

        if (ip.equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1")) {
            InetAddress localip;
            try {
                localip = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                ip = localip.getHostAddress();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return ip;
    }
}
```